# ¿Que falta por configurar? IP estática en Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux

necesito configurar este servidor con Ubuntu 16.04, el inconveniente es que al intentar levantar el `networking.service` se manifiesta el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La configuracion aplicada es la siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución a esto fue realizar el procedimiento por **interfaz gráfica** desde la maquina virtual, ya que al parecer la edición del archivo interfaces desde **SSH** no se configura de manera correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Si ejecutas el comando que te indica, te saldrá donde falla.

journalctl -xe

Mira si se llama realmente eth0 la tarjeta de red, muchas veces les pone otro nombre. 
Con el comando dmesg |grep eth te tendría que salir como se llama la tarjeta de red.